# how to redirect from folder in a web server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xml

i have two different applications, one is a website project running on the the server root, the second is a web application project in a folder, both projects have their configuration files, and i am putting the link in the configuration file of the website project

i am trying to redirect users from the website project to the web application project, whenever i use this:

```
<add key="CoronaPortalAddress" value="http://localhost/coronaportal/Security/ApplicantSignIn1.aspx?applicationType=" />
<add key="CoronaPortalSignInPage" value="http://localhost/coronaportal/Security/SignIn.aspx" />
<add key="CoronaPortalTimeTablePage" value="http://localhost/coronaportal/Conona Schools_ Trust Council_ApplicantTestScores/TimeTable1.aspx" />
<add key="CoronaPortalResultsPage" value="http://localhost/coronaportal/ParentReportLogin.aspx" />
```

users will be redirected, though on the url it will showing localhost, so i change it to:

```
<add key="CoronaPortalAddress" value="http://www.shodsystems.com/coronaportal/Security/ApplicantSignIn1.aspx?applicationType=" />
<add key="CoronaPortalSignInPage" value="http://www.shodsystems.com/coronaportal/Security/SignIn.aspx" />
<add key="CoronaPortalTimeTablePage" value="http://www.shodsystems.com/coronaportal/Conona Schools_ Trust Council_ApplicantTestScores/TimeTable1.aspx" />
<add key="CoronaPortalResultsPage" value="http://www.shodsystems.comcoronaportal/ParentReportLogin.aspx" />
```

now it throwing error:

```
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS
```

i tried to google this, but couldnt fix it, any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your folder in configured as application in iis?

Comment: No, please how do i do that, i am hosting with Godaddy

Comment: https://www.godaddy.com/help/customize-iis-settings-3971

Comment: Its because you did not set virtual directory for this application

Comment: @Imad, any link as to how to do it?

Comment: The webpage could be blocked.  Make sure you can get to webpage using IE webbrowser manually on PCs that aren't working.